# Why is the below Python program showing error?

Tags: python, openpyxl

On executing the below code it shows error

> load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'read_only'

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename="textxl.xlsx", read_only = True)
wb2 = Workbook()

print wb.get_sheet_names()
wb2 = wb
wb2.save('balances.xlsx')
```

I want to know the reason

Comment: Have you tried `load_workbook(filename="textxl.xlsx", True)`?

Comment: The function `load_workbook()` does not have any arguments named `read_only`.  Check the documentation for the library and call the function correctly.

Comment: What version of this library do you have? Are you reading the documentation for the same version that you are using?

Comment: Try using use_iterators=True , instead of read_only ?

Comment: Looks like `read_only` was introduced in [`v2.1`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/api/openpyxl.reader.html?highlight=load_workbook#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook). It wasn't there in [`v2.0`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.0/openpyxl.reader.html?highlight=load_workbook#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook). Which version are you using?